# error importing tensorflow on python 3.6.3 windows10

Tags: python

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
```

(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXX>python
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import tensorflow as tf
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
> > >           fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(**file**)])
> > >         File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
> > >           raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
> > >       ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 54, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 60, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(**file**)])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 54, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with python 3.6 and tensorflow....I downgraded python version to 3.5.4 ...It's working well.... no issue to import tensorflow.